# Disable Print to file option in PDF.js

Tags: java, pdf, web-applications, printing, pdf.js

I am using PDF.js to display PDFs in the browser. The application is a Java based Web application . The PDF must not be saved locally on the users machine and must be used to printing only. For this i have disabled the download and save options.

The user can still save the PDF using print to file option or using cutePDF among others. Is there any way i can control this using PDF.js or any other viewer/solution?

Thanks & Regards
Tinto Chacko

Comment: How is this relevant to Java?

Comment: At the end of the day the user can still zoom in really far and take screenshots, the result is a high resolution image of the pdf file. No solution here just a thought.

Comment: i wanted to know if any other solution exists in java. I know it is a bad requirement as there are many ways to get hold of the PDF data.

Comment: Deploy custom version of PDF.js and disable print button? CSS can control what's printed via @media print

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this short of installing a device driver on the user's computer, which is ineffective (as there are still workarounds), likely to cause malfunctions (such as screwing up network printers), and hostile to your users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. there is no other way? I am aware of Digital Rights Management (DRM) System which will secure PDF effectively. want to know if anything else can be done.

Comment: @user1911966 That's exactly the sort of user-hostile thing I mean. Even Adobe DRM wouldn't effectively "protect" you against soft printers.